# How can I delete image of AWS S3 bucket from Angular side?

Tags: angularjs

```
s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', param, function(err, url) {
    Console.log(url);
});
```

This method is used to add an image. Should I use it to delete the image from Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3({
        params: {
          Bucket: bucketName
        },
        accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey
      });

      var params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Delimiter: '/',
        Prefix:  "/"
      }

      var ok = "";
      s3.listObjects(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.Contents.length; i++) {
          if (data.Contents[i].Key.indexOf(remainingKey) > -1) {
            ok = data.Contents[i].Key;
            var params1 = {
              Bucket: bucketName,
              Key: ok
            };
            s3.deleteObject(params1, function (err, data) {

            });
          }
        }
      });
```

For more details http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#deleteBucket-property

Comment: `var params1 = {
              Bucket: bucketName,
              Key: ok
            };

            s3.deleteObject(params1, function (err, data) {

            });`
It's required only this much